# UTC Timestamp and timezone - Any relation?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, timezone, momentjs

I came across the following snippet, which sets the default timezone for moment as `Asia/Kolkata` and has a function named `getUTCUnixTimestamp` that (apparently) calculates the timestamp in UTC given the moment object.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Kolkata");

const getUTCUnixTimestamp = function (momentObject) {
    const fmt = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
    return moment.utc(moment(momentObject).format(fmt)).unix()
}
```

My question is this:

- What is the purpose of setting up a timezone in the second statement? What is this statement doing?

If the function just wants to calculate timestamp in UTC, then what is the purpose of setting up a timezone `Asia/Kolkata` which is `+5:30`?

Comment: It would read the current date *as* that timezone, then convert it to a Unix timestamp, shifting the time appropriately. I'm not really sure it's needed - I'd think Moment already has a way to handle input from a given timezone. And Unix timestamps are *always* in UTC, so the juggling there seems a bit superfluous.

Comment: @VLAZ How would you do this, if you want Unix timestamp converted to `Asia/Kolkata` timezone? This is what I want to do

Comment: Unix timestamps are *always* in UTC. You cannot have a timestamp "in a timezone" - they simply have none (or a single one: `+0`). You have to read the timestamp, then apply the offset.

Comment: @VLAZ What is the function `getUTCUnixTimestamp` exactly doing?

Comment: It takes some `momentObject` (I assume an instance of Moment with some date set), then formats the date it contains into ISO 8601 format without a timezone offset. That string is fed into `moment.utc()` which will read it as UTC and shift it to match the local timezone (which is set globally). So, if you gave it `2020-11-09 05:45:37` you'd get a date set to `2020-11-09 05:45:37Z` and with local time equal to `2020-11-09 11:15:37+05:30`. Finally, it converts that final object to a Unix timestamp which is `1604900737` with that date.

Comment: @VLAZ How is this different from simple `moment().unix()`

Comment: It *most likely* isn't. Hence why I said that all the juggling is superfluous. I'd assume that all that's needed is to do `return momentObject.unix()`. But I don't know what `momentObject` is. It might not be a moment instance for all I know. At best, you could take the object apply your local timezone (don't want to check the docs for how) and then call `.unix()`. Might not be relevant, though.

Comment: @VLAZ If I do `moment.utc(moment(moment()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")).unix() - moment().unix()`  , I get `19800` Not sure what is hapening.

Comment: Because you're doing a very roundabout check of the timezone offset. `moment.utc(moment(moment()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")).unix()` is going to be something like `2020-11-09 11:15:37Z` while `moment().unix()` is `2020-11-09 11:15:37+05:30` - same *time* set but it's 5:30 hours apart due to it representing different time zones. So, you're getting the difference in seconds and getting `5 * 60 * 60 + 30 * 60 = 19800` difference between the two.

Comment: Okay. If I store the timestamps in UTC which simply would be `moment().unix()` , how could I query the stored timestamps in the local timezone? Could you give an example? This I what I am looking for.

Comment: `moment.unix(timestamp)` is all you need. It would read the date as a Unix timestamp and convert it for you `moment.unix(1604900737)` will give you `2020-11-09 05:45:30Z`/`2020-11-09 11:15:37+05:30` assuming your local timezone is set with `moment.tz.setDefault()`. Alternatively, it's `moment.unix(1604900737).utcOffset("+05:30")` to read it as a Unix timestamp and apply the timezone you want. You can then print it via `.format` [or whatever](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

Comment: In general, one should never format an object to a string just to parse that string back into an object (ever, any language, any object).  Thus, I agree with VLAZ, the code shown is a roundabout way to do things that are already provided by built-in functions.  It will have different behavior depending on the state of the object being passed in, thus it is error prone.  Also, Please keep in mind the [moment project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's relevant because timezones are relative to each other, meaning that if the website is in GTM+1 the transformation to UTC (GMT+0) is different than if the website is in GMT+5.

I guess the website is managing dates in that timezone, possibly even the DB too (though I would recommend storing dates in UTC), so Moment needs to know that when you pass it a 19:00 for UTC conversion it has to add/substract X hours.

Comment: What is the function `getUTCUnixTimestamp` actually doing? It applies `UTC` to a moment object and then calculates the unix timestamp. If I store timestamps simply as UTC which is `moment().unix()`. Then how can I query a timestamp for the timezone I want?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: A timestamp is always in UTC so you cannot query a timestamp for a timezone, because it doesn't have one. It is implicitly UTC time. So knowing this, which is a standard, you can transform a timestamp to any timezone using a UTC to any specific timezone conversion.

Comment: Could you give a code example covering this case? It will be helpful.